# Atleast K out of N encoding in SAT solvers

Tags: constraint-programming, sat, sat-solvers

I know that given an at most k out of N tool I can get an at least K out of N by changing it to at most (n-k) out of N.

But I can't seem to wrap my head around how this is true. I might be missing something very trivial

For example, if K=2 and N=6 how is at least 2 out of 6 equivalent to at most 4 out of 6

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you put it, the equivalence just isn't true. So, don't feel bad about not understanding it. To see, let's take an example. Let's say we have booleans only, N=`6` and K=`2`, and the assignment:

```
True False False False False False
```

to these 6 variables. The statement `At most 2 out of 6 are True` is obviously satisfied by this assignment, but `At least 4 out of 6 are True` is not.

Maybe what you meant is:

> at least K out of N is True

is equivalent to

> at most N-K out of N is False

which can be further generalized to say:

> at least K out of N objects have property P

is equivalent to:

> at most N-K out of N objects do *not* have the property P

Is this what you were trying to express? Hope that's more clear!

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer!